Event Trigger to apply triggers to new tables
I am trying to implement functionality to automatically apply triggers to any new "items" tables
as they are created.
I tried to do this using an EVENT TRIGGER, firstly with this function:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.apply_trigger_on_item_table_creation()
RETURNS event_trigger AS $$
DECLARE
    obj record;
BEGIN
    FOR obj IN
        SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()
    LOOP
        IF obj.object_type = 'table' AND obj.object_identity LIKE '%.items' THEN
            EXECUTE format('
                CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER item_create_trigger
                AFTER INSERT ON %I
                FOR EACH ROW
                EXECUTE FUNCTION public.sync_insert();', obj.object_identity);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Then created an event trigger ON ddl_command_end:
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER create_item_table_trigger
ON ddl_command_end
WHEN TAG IN ('CREATE TABLE')
EXECUTE FUNCTION apply_trigger_on_item_table_creation();

However, when I try and do a CREATE TABLE test.items, I get the following error:
ERROR:  relation "test.items" does not exist
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "
                CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER item_create_trigger
                AFTER INSERT ON "test.items"
                FOR EACH ROW
                EXECUTE FUNCTION public.sync_insert();"
PL/pgSQL function apply_trigger_on_wi_table_creation() line 12 at EXECUTE 
SQL state: 42P01

Even though this trigger is called ON ddl_command_end, the table does not exist until the trigger exits.
Is there a native PostgreSQL solution to this problem? Perhaps using LISTEN/NOTIFY? Thanks!

object_type contains both the schema name and the table name. You can't use a single identity placeholder %I to escape them both. You need two placeholders, one for the schema and one for the table. And split obj.object_identity before

The problem is that the double quotes in "test.items" make the database take this for the table name rather than a schema qualified table (which would be test.items or "test"."items").
The documentation says that




Name
Type
Description




...
...
...


object_identity
text
Text rendering of the object identity, schema-qualified. Each identifier included in the identity is quoted if necessary.




So you can use %s like
EXECUTE format(
           E'CREATE TRIGGER item_create_trigger\n'
           'AFTER INSERT ON %s\n'
           'FOR EACH ROW\n'
           'EXECUTE FUNCTION public.sync_insert();',
           obj.object_identity
        );


Great answer, thanks!
One follow-up question: Is there any difference between using format as I did in the question, versus using the E escape operator, and with each line as a new string?

No. It is just a harmless syntax variant. Choose what you like better.

EDIT: As the legendary Laurenz Albe answered, this solution is overly complicated, and a simple %s placeholder fixes the issue.
As Frank Heikens pointed out, the problem was not with the timing, but the fact that the schema + table name were being written into the CREATE TRIGGER SQL as a single string ("test.items" instead of test.items).
To fix this, I made the following changes to apply_trigger_on_item_table_creation():

Declare variables for the separated schema and table names:

DECLARE
    obj record;
    new_schema TEXT;
    new_table TEXT;


Split obj.object_identity:

new_schema := split_part(obj.object_identity, '.', 1);
new_table := split_part(obj.object_identity, '.', 2);


Modify format to accept 2 identity placeholders:

EXECUTE format('
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER item_create_trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON %I.%I
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION public.sync_insert();', new_schema, new_table);

